# How can i approach these 2 elements on my header?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 2 elements(**h1** and **h2**) aligned by flexbox, and i don't know how to make them come close to each other, here is the code:

```css
header {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(129, 187, 70, 0.795);
    height: 20%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

header h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 200;
}

header h2 {
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
        <header>
            <h1>Text 1</h1>
            <h2>
              Text 2(<span class="color-1">?</span>,<span class="color-2">?</span>,<span class="color-3">?</span>)
            </h2>
        </header>
```

Comment: flex-direction: row; ?

Comment: reducing default margin or padding is what you are looking for .

Comment: I want one above the other, like this @Sfili_81.

Comment: As said put `margin:0` in you `h1` `h2` CSS

Comment: @Rana it worked, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Heading tags like H1 and H2 already comes with default CSS values. H1, for example, has this ones:

```
display: block;
font-size: 2em;
margin-top: 0.67em;
margin-bottom: 0.67em;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
font-weight: bold;
```

So, as Rana said above, you will have to define a margin: 0 or another value that will suit your case.

Here is a list with all the CSS default values that all the HTML elements will have: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp